# Django how to assign a function for sending emails from to an HTML button

Tags: html, django, button

I am new to django and i would like to know how i can give the function "Initial_Report(request):" to an html button so that every time is clicked it performs the given function.

**Views code**

```
def home(request):

return render(request, 'home.html')

def Initial_Report(request):

noc_emails = Employee.objects.exclude(Position__Position__contains='Customer').values_list('Email', flat=True)
cs_emails = Employee.objects.filter(Position__Position__contains = 'Customer').values_list('Email', flat=True)

noc_message = ('Initial Outage Report', 'This is a new outage report ,The information is in the document', 'from@example.com', noc_emails)
cs_message = ('Initial Outage Report', 'This is a new outage report ,The information is in the document', 'from@example.com', cs_emails)
send_mass_mail((noc_message,cs_message), fail_silently=False)

return render(request,'InitialReport.html')
```

**Urls**

```
urlpatterns = [

path('', views.home, name='home.html'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('Initial_Report', views.Initial_Report, name = 'Initial_Report' ),

]
```

**Home.html**

```
<button> Send Initial Report</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `Initial_Report` is called when /Initial_Report is triggered

```
path('Initial_Report', views.Initial_Report, name = 'Initial_Report' ),
```

You can add a link to the path

```
<a href= "/Initial_Report"> Send Initial Report</a>
```